# I had invented and published before this patent application - How do I get it invalidated?

Tags: prior-art, us9883333b2, wo2014170646a1, gb1307148.5, gb2513196a

In reference to the patent: [PCT/GB2014/051152](https://patentscope.wipo.int/search/en/detail.jsf?docId=WO14/170646) [WO 2014/170646 A1](https://www.google.com/patents/WO2014170646A1) granted and pending patents: GB1307148.5, GB1500104.3 and GB1500105.0 to What3Words Limited:

Here is the screenshot from the video I had published on [YouTube on 10th of April 2013](http://youtu.be/LfGeIWCeeKU?t=321) that showed 5 words for Mt. Everest's location:
[image: Video screenshot showing 5 words for a geo co-ordinate]

Additionally here is crowd funding campaign page on [IndieGogo started on 11th of April 2013](https://www.indiegogo.com/projects/wcode-encode-with-words/x/2245741#/story)

Also here is the UK-IPO patent application record's screenshot **filed by What3Words just 9 days after my video**:
[image: UK IPO patent filing screenshot with application date]

Another record is available from [archive.org](http://web.archive.org/web/*/wcodes.org).

The only effective difference is that What3Words uses three words while my system would take up around 5 words - but mine is more simpler and thus more effective as it uses words from a much smaller set of only 1024 very common and unambiguous words.

How do I get these patents invalidated?

I tried submitting a `third party observation` but was unable to since the `priority date` is past 28 months limit.

**Update 1**: I submitted my documents under the `third party observation` to the UK IPO office via email as per [Submitting observations concerning the patentability of an invention](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/submitting-observations-concerning-the-patentability-of-an-invention). I then received an auto generated email acknowledging the receipt.

**Update 2**: Sadly, the patent was granted as [US9883333B2](https://patents.google.com/patent/US9883333B2/en) on 2018-01-30

**Update 3**: The UK International Patent Office had included references to my publications in their [patent examination report for GB1307148 dated - 6th March 2018](https://www.ipo.gov.uk/p-ipsum/Document/ApplicationNumber/GB1307148.5/f8ae7cba-4a0f-46e5-9aa5-9169934500b9/GB2513196-20180306-Exam%20report%20%20Standard.pdf)[image: Citation - highlighted : Ujjwal Singh - Inventive step]

**Update 4**: WIPO has included references to my publications in their patent document [WO2014170646A1](https://patents.google.com/patent/WO2014170646A1#:%7E:text=by%20third%20party-,Non%2DPatent%20Citations,-(2))
[image: Citation - highlighted : Ujjwal Singh]

Comment: My app for location codes is available at: https://wolo.codes/get

Comment: More info available at: https://wcodes.org/patents

Comment: Still pending at the European Patent Register as `EP2987344`: https://register.epo.org/application?tab=doclist&number=EP14719814&lng=en

Comment: @chrki thank you, I have submitted my *observations* to the European Patent Register

Comment: Yes, USA patent has been granted. This surprises me considering the way the US patent was worded.
Any update on the UK or European patent?
I have a USA patent on a competing location encdoing technology. European patent also applied for.

Comment: @Merton - This is your "answer" turned into a comment. It was not actually an answer to the question and the content was that of a comment. You do not have the minimum 50 rep points that are required to have permission to post a comment. See this meta question to understand why that is an SE policy. meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/….

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can tell, the patent has only issued in the US. You can file a Post Grant Review within 9 months of the grant date of January 30, 2018. [This article](https://www.lexology.com/library/detail.aspx?g=aac8d580-73bc-487b-9289-b9b73dde3166) describes the options for challenging the patent.

Answer (score 3):

the reference to the "Patent" that you cited isn't actually a granted patent, it's only an application that has been published by the USPTO. 
If you are interested in submitting what you have done so that the patent examiners are aware of it, you can do it by following these directions: http://www.uspto.gov/patent/initiatives/third-party-preissuance-submissions

Comment: Thanks Alex. This is a WIPO (PCT) patent. Unfortunately we are past 28 month limit and thus I am unable to submit a `third party observation`

Comment: The question has nothing to do with the USPTO. It clearly relates to the UKIPO.